# How does ORACLE DB sum NUMBER(*,s) with many records?

Tags: oracle, numbers, rounding-error

I am wondering how Oracle sums `NUMBER(9,2)` with `SUM(numWithScale/7)`.

This is because I am wondering how the error will propagate with a large amount of records

Let's say I have a table `EMP_SAL` with some `EMP_ID, numWithScale`, `numWithScale` being a salary.

To make it simple, let us make the `numWithScale` column `NUMBER(9,2)` 9 decimals of precision with 2 decimals to round to. All of these numbers in the table are random digits from 10.00-20.00 (ex. 10.12, 20.00, 19.95)

I divide by 7 in my calculation to give random digits at the end that round up or down.

Now, I sum all of the employees salaries with `SUM(numWithScale/7)`.

Will the sum round each time it adds a record? Or does Oracle round after the calculation is complete? i.e. the error can be +/-0.01 from rounding, and with many additions then roundings, error adds up. Or does it round at the end? Thus I dont have to worry about the error adding up (unless I use the result in many more calculations)

Also, will Oracle return the sum as the more precise `NUMBER`, (38 digit precision, floating point)? or will it round up to the second digit `NUMBER(9,2)` when returning the value?

Will MSSQL behave pretty much the same way (even though syntax is different?

Comment: What do you get if you compare `SUM(numWithScale/7)` to `SUM(numWithScale) / 7`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oracle performs operation in the order you specified.

So, if you write this query:

```
select SUM(numWithScale/7) from some_table -- (1)
```

each of values divided by 7 and rounded to maximum available precision: [`NUMBER` with 38 significant digits](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/datatype.htm#CNCPT1832). After that all digits are summed.

In case of this query:

```
select SUM(numWithScale)/7 from some_table -- (2)
```

all `numWithScale` values are summed and only after that divided by 7. In this case there are no precision loss for each record, only result of `sum()` division by 7 are rounded to 38 significant digits.

This problem are common for calculation algorithms. Each time when you divide value by 7 you produce small calculation error because of limited number of digits, representing a number:
 `numWithScale/7 => quotient + delta`.
While summing this values you got
`sum(quotient) + sum(delta)`.

If `numWithScale` represents ideal uniform distribution and and a `some_table` contains infinite number of records, then `sum(delta)` tends to zero. But it happens only in theory. In practical cases `sum(delta)` grows and introduces significant error. This is a case of  query`(1)`.

On the other hand, summing can't introduce a rounding error if [implemented  properly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kahan_summation_algorithm). So for query (2) rounding error introduced only in last step, when whole sum divided by 7. Therefore value of `delta` for this query not affected by number of records.

Answer (score 2):

Number scale and precision is only relevant as column or variable constraint.

When you attempt to store a number that exceeds defined precision it will raise an exception:

```
create table num (a number(5,2));
insert into num values (123456.789);
=> ORA-01438: value larger than specified precision allowed for this column
```

When you attempt to store a number that exceeds defined scale it will be rounded:

```
insert into num values (123.456789);
select a from num;
=> 123.46
```

Precision and scale do not matter when you read data and perform any calculations on it...

```
select 100000 + a / 100 from num;
=> 100001.2346
```

...unless you want to store it back into column with constraints, so above rules apply:

```
update num set a = a / 100;
select a from num;
=> 1.23
```

Answer (score 1):

`numWithScale/7` will be converted to NUMBER (i.e. it will not be rounded to number(9,2)).